# ¿Cómo cargar el DataGrid más rápido desde C# con base de datos en SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo cargar mi *DataGrid* mas rápido? Mi problema reside en que al cargar el *form* que contiene el *DataGrid* este se demora en cargar y tengo pocos registros en la base de datos en *SQL*.

El código que uso para el *DataGrid* es:

```
private void FormAlumnos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable TablaAlumnos = new DataTable();
    TablaAlumnos = Datos.ObtenerAlumnos();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = TablaAlumnos;
}
```

El código para hacer la conexión a *SQL* y obtener los *Alumnos* es:

```
//Obtener Alumnos//////////
public static DataTable ObtenerAlumnos()
{
    DataTable TablaAlumnos = new DataTable();
    AbrirConexion();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ObtenerAlumnos", conexion);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(TablaAlumnos);
    CerrarConexion();
    return TablaAlumnos;

}
```

Comment: Cuando dices poco registros a cuentos haces referencia ? podrias poner el codigo que usas para cargar los datos del grid

Comment: Son menos de 100 registros...y se porta como si cargara 5000

Answer (score 2):

Si bien 100 registros parece poca cantidad representarlos algo de tiempo lleva un tiempo, por eso existe el `modo virtual` que podria ayudar

[Tutorial: Implementar el modo virtual en el control DataGridView de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control)

Para esto asigna en `true` la propiedad

[DataGridView.VirtualMode Propiedad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=netframework-4.8)

Sino el otro camino sera implementar filtros o paginado de los datos para que carguen menos cantidad visualmente en el grid

[Implement Paging DataGridView in Windows Forms (WinForms) Application using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

como veras usando el datagridview la paginacion de los datos hay que codificarla uno mismo

Comment: de donde obtuviste ese valor de que un control debes aguantar esa cantidad de registros? es algo oficial en alguna documentacion o solo lo inventaste

Comment: necesita, debe? el control no necesita nada, tu funcionalidad lo requiere, si ves que demora en cargar aplica otras tecnicas, la que comento del virtual mode es una de ellas, si aun con esa no funciona entonces vas a tener que pagina, o aplicar filtros para reducir la cantidad de registros que muestras al usuario.

Comment: si redusco la cantidad de registro, Cómo veria el resto?

Comment: Paginando, podrias crear pagina de al 10 registros, y tener botones para ir de una pagina a otra navegando, pero bueno esto hay que programarlo si solo usas el DataGridView, en otros componentes de terceros viene implementado

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando un ejemplo de como paginar los datos

Comment: Mira lo que quiero lograr. es una base de tados de estudiantes con todos sus datos personales y datos academicos. Una base de datos asi son muchisimas personas las que estarian registradas y el problema es que se pega con 31 registros apenas, por paginacion me decias lo acabo de intentar y nada igual cn el modo virtual.

Comment: Implementaste el paginado en tiempo record, como pudiste validar que 31 registros no funciona? prueba paginar de a 20 o de a 10 registros, lo que no entiendo es que velocidad de respuesta estas buscando.

Comment: Si son muchas personas, entonces implementa filtros, permite buscar por nombre, documento o legajo del estudiante y ve directo a ese dato, para que listar si en definitiva solo vas a trabajar cin una entidad a la vez. Cuando quieras listas genera un reporte

Answer (score 2):

No utilize Datatable porque tienden a empeorar el performance y utilize programación asíncrona. Recorra un SQLDataReader en lugar de llenar un datatable. Suponiendo que la clase Alumno tiene solo una propiedad : Nombre:

Puede crear una lista de Alumnos:

```
private async void FormAlumnos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
List<Alumno> alumnos=new List<Alumno>();

 using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=xxx;Initial Catalog=xx;User Id=xx;Password=xx;"))
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();

                    using (var comando = new SqlCommand(sentencia, con))
                    {

                       comando .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();



                           while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                            {
                                alumnos.Add(new Alumno{

                                 Nombre=reader["Nombre"].toString()
                                });
                            }

                    }
                }


Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{

dataGridView1.DataSource = alumnos;

}));


}
```

Comment: Me parece una buena recomendación el uso de `async`, sin embargo tengo una pregunta: _"No utilize `Datatable` porque tienden a empeorar el performance "_ está documentado en algún lugar esto?

Comment: Obviamente eso no va a estar documentado porque microsoft no va a hablar mal de sus productos a menos que saquen algo mejor. Eso no solo lo digo yo que en mi experiencia tanto datatables como entity framework me han dado problemas de rendimiento. Muchos programadores que han trabajado con esto opinan lo mismo. Aunque tengo que decir que en la versión más reciente de entity framework core va bastante bien pero las anteriores versiones en mi opinión no.

Comment: Los datatables cargan los datos en memoria y con esto no hay problema si se trabaja con pocos datos, pero en mi caso he tenido que trabajar con millones de registros y como comprendera cargar todo eso en memoria no es buena idea. Siempre me ha funciona bien, rápido y eficiente usar un SQLDataReader y usar mi propio código para hacer las operacioness en la bd en lugar de usar entity framework. Si a usted le funciona bien los datatables pues siga usandolos. Pero piense que Microsoft nunca va a documentar que sus cosas van mal o que hay cosas mejores que las de ellos.

Comment: Disculpa si has mal interpretado mi pregunta, solo es una forma de explciar el porqué, me parece que tu respuesta fue buena y voté a favor. No lo tomes a mal, como te explico es una forma de que lo que se dice, se explique el porque :)

Comment: Richard gracias por comentar y respeto y agradezco tu aporte la tomo en cuenta porque la paginacion no me fue bien ya ni carga la base de datos en el form se detiene...pero mira en la base de no solo tengo la propiedad Nombre, también Apellidos ,Edad,Dirección, etc...recomiendame un buen tutorial para saber mas como aplicar DataReader.

Comment: Documentación oficial de microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8. También puede ver este tutorial de youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_p5RWMsjtY